# Change navigation drawer item from activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to change a `NavDrawer` item text from any activity or fragment?

For example I show a progress in a navdrawer item (Progress: 25%) and when the user clicks on this, an activity opens up with detailed analytics. This is basic. What I want is when the user does something inside the app in any activity - even when the navdrawer is not displayed - I want to update this percent so the next time the user opens the navdrawer, it says Progress: 30%.

I haven't found anything about this in Google.

Comment: Are you using a base class for your navdrawer? Could you just update the string resource you're using to display progress?

Comment: I am using a customized navdrawer. It does not work with normal getter-setter methods